# Divide into groups with approximately equal count of rows and draw bars with average values

Tags: python, pandas

I have many rows in:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['param_1', 'param_2', ..., 'param_n'])
```

and I need to group rows into several groups and display stacked bars with averaged values:

```py
bin_count = 10
step = math.ceil(df.shape[0] / bin_count)
df['p'] = 0
for i in range(0, df.shape[0], step):
    df.iloc[i:i + step]['p'] = i
df_group = df.groupby('p').mean()
df_group.plot.bar(stacked = True)
```

How to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.qcut` to split the DataFrame by passing it a `range` based on the length of the DataFrame.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 111 rows to split into (10) groups
Nr = 111
df = pd.DataFrame({'param_1': np.random.randint(0, 10, Nr),
                   'param_2': range(Nr)})
```

#### Code

```
# Number of bins
bin_count = 10  
df_group = df.groupby(pd.qcut(range(len(df)), bin_count, labels=False)).mean()

df_group.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)
```

[image]

---

This will form groups as close to evenly sized as possible given the length of your data, similar to `np.array_split`

```
df.groupby(pd.qcut(range(len(df)), bin_count, labels=False)).size()

0    12
1    11
2    11
3    11
4    11
5    11
6    11
7    11
8    11
9    11
dtype: int64
```